# PG4Admin "local variable 'debugger_version' "?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

My Postgres version is 9.6, running on Windows 7 Professional.

I have just upgraded to pgAdmin 4.2.3 since I was not able to get the debugger to work at all with my previous pgAdmin. I installed using the Windows binary.

I have set `postgresql.conf`  for `shared_preload_libraries = '$libdir/plugin_debugger.dll'`, restarted Postgres, added extension `pldbgapi`, and made sure I had admin permissions.

I am now able to select either 'debug' or 'set breakpoint', but at 'set breakpoint' or when I click 'debug' after entering input parameters, I get:

> "local variable 'debugger_version' referenced before assignment".

Did I miss something in installation or configuration? Note that I did install from a binary, not by compiling the source. (I posted this question on the pgadmin support mailing list a couple of weeks back but have gotten no response.)

Comment: Well, to me it looks like a bug in pgAdmin4.

Comment: @dezso Yes, but it looked to me like the type of bug that would have been caught by compile time and never made it as far as a released program, so I have been hoping for a different explanation, ideally something I could fix without tracking down and correcting the bug myself and rebuilding from the source. I have started looking into omnidb, which also has a debugger, but so far I have not gotten that debugger to work as advertised either.

Comment: Hi @mickeyf , I'm one of developers of OmniDB. Can you please give me more details about the issue you are facing when using the OmniDB debugger? Please open an issue here: https://github.com/OmniDB/OmniDB/issues
Thanks in advance.